# Can you run SQL distribution agent as service account and connect to distributor with windows account or does it have to be a SQL account?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

Setup: 2 SQL Server 2022 instances, `PubServer` and `SubServer`.

Configured `PubServer` as publisher, `SubServer` as subscriber.

`PubServer` has transactional publication created and working. Share and file permissions setup according to MS recommendations and "repl" share and its contents are accessible. The domain `sql_dist` account has been added to the PAL.

`SubServer` pull subscription is created, but the job history reports an error

> The process could not connect to Distributor

Distribution Agent Security setup as shown in screenshot:

[image]

I've tried running the agent under the `domain\sql_dist` account, but the job fails with error

> A required privilege is not held by the client

So, running as the SQL Server Agent account (`NT Service\SQLServerAgent`) allows agent to run on `SubServer`, but then it seems the agent either can't pass specific Windows credentials to the `PubServer` or the account just doesn't have a required permission on `PubServer`.

Does the "Use the following SQL Server Login" option mean ONLY SQL Server accounts or can it be a Windows account, too?